# fixed height div on bottom, variable height on top

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I need to create a page that has two divs. There is a bottom one of fixed height that must always be visible, no matter the size of the page. All the space above it (if there is any) should then be allocated to the other div which will contain a canvas. The canvas can be of varying height, large or small, depending on data and other conditions. If it's larger than the space allocated, I'd like to have a scrollbar appear

I'm getting close. I can get the bottom div to always be visible via position:absolute and bottom:0. But I can't get the behavior I'm looking for for the top div, which is to expand to fill the rest of the space above the fixed bottom but not beyond if the canvas is big.

Edit: here is the code:

```
.top {
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 20px;
}
```

There is javascript later that generates the canvas in the top div; based on server side code, it can be of arbitrary height.

What I have above looks right, but I want to remove the height: 500px from the top div to have it expand to use all the remaining available space on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood you want a footer to be always visible and the content could be of varying height. What I would basically do is

```
// Create a padding to allow all content to be visible
body { padding-bottom: 5em; }

footer
{
    // Move it to the bottom and fix it to the view
    position: fixed; bottom: 0px;
    // Give it its dimensions. Height should be the same or less than the body bottom-padding.
    height: 5em; width: 100%;
}
```

Here is an example: http://tinkerbin.com/gF303DsM

Comment: I'm not sure this covers the entire question - "I want to... have it expand to use all the remaining available space on the screen."

Comment: How doesn't it? It can continue expanding with content, the footer is fixed. It won't work in IE though, you would need to switch the footer tag for a div.